# OpenJDK, Oracle JDK and JCP

Tags: java

As I understand, Oracle is moving its Oracle JDK to a feature release every 6 months and a Oracle JDK LTS every 3 years or so. Oracle JDK will no longer be free after January 2019. It seems that OpenJDK is also moving to a 6 months release cycle.

My questions are:

- How is Oracle JDK and OpenJDK keeping up with the Java Specifications
  if feature releases are released so often?
- Will OpenJDK also adopt the LTS as a reference implementation to
  match the Java Specifications? [Answer, yes. See [here](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-and-zulu-enterprise/zulu-enterprise-java-support-options/): "Oracle and the OpenJDK community are moving to a Long Term Support (LTS) release model plus a new class of “Feature” releases."

Thanks!

Comment: Updates for Oracle Java 8 beyond January 2019 will only be available through a commercial license as far as I'm aware. At this time the LTS version 18.9 (aka Java 11) should already be available according to [Oracle's roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) which should provide free updates on a regular basis until the next LTS version is shipped. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: @RomanVottner Agreed, Oracle Java 11 LTS will only be available through commercial license after 03/2019. My question is regards the Java Specifications (since OpenJDK is the reference implementation currently) and if OpenJDK will adopt the LTS notion (like Oracle JDK does) for specification compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's address some misconceptions in the question.

> Oracle JDK will no longer be free after January 2019.

[From what I've read](https://medium.com/codefx-weekly/no-free-java-lts-version-b850192745fb), *only* the LTS version will require a paid license.  The public version will remain free but will only be supported for as long as there's not a *new* version out.  I surmised as much from [Oracle's own roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/eol-135779.html) in which they list 18.3 as being supported until September 2018.

Now to the main question:  Oracle hasn't changed the specs of the JVM just because they've moved to a 6-month release cycle.  What *has* changed is what features land in a specific version at any given time.  Instead of the typical (and oddly familiar) glacial pace of features, we get releases if they're ready within a six-month window.

The only thing that's really changed there is the pace of release and what potentially lands in a release, not the specs.

(Also, OpenJDK and Oracle JDK will become one and the same Soon™.  They're working on this.)

Comment: Thanks for the noted clarification. In the [past](https://youtu.be/YauqubC8FKM?t=16m30s) , major releases corresponded to changes to the Java Specifications while minor versions corresponded to a patches, bugs, etc. For example, a major feature that changes the spec could not be introduced in a minor release. With this change, Oracle will introduce 'major' features in the 6 months releases. Will the specifications be updated frequently to match the six-month window?

Comment: I would presume so.  We'd have to look back [at the specs page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) to see in September, though.